# prove that $\lim_{x \to a}(h_1(x)+h_2(x))f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a}g(x)$ exist and

$\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}(h_1(x)g(x)+h_2(x)f(x))$ exist

prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to a}(h_1(x)+h_2(x))f(x)$ exist

I would be really happy if someone could help me.

Comment: Are $f,g$ supposed to be defined at $a$ (what is their domain?). When you say the limit exists, can it be $+\infty$, or must it exist in $\mathbb{R}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Counterexample:**
Let $a=0$, $f(x)=x$, $g(x)=x^2$ and for $x\ne 0$ let $h_1(x)=\frac1{x^2}$, $h_2(x)=\frac1x$.

Comment: oh!!,thank you so much